# Silverlight file transfer using WCF

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I have a question regarding the technology available rather than a solution to the problem I'm facing.

I have implemented a client in Silverlight and a server using WCF, using `basicHttpBinding` with some modifications.

The SL client can upload as many files as he wishes. The uploading process is done by dividing the file into chunks and send it async.

There were 2 issues I had to face:

1. Server receives the files not by their sending order / fixed by creating a simple buffer.
2. The client receives a finished event only when the chunk is being sent rather than when its being processed / implemented another `OperationContract` for `IsFinished`.

My question is am I doing it right? Is there a mechanism that does the buffering itself? I don't mind sharing the code although its working OK.

Thanks!
Moshe

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you decided to send your files in chunks.  I'm guessing perhaps due to the size of files you're transferring?.  One possible alternative approach to this would be using WCF streaming.  Take a look at the following for details on why to use streaming and how to set it up:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2010/07/08/using-transfermode-streamedresponse-to-download-files-in-silverlight-4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks for replying.

The thing is, as i understand, Silverlight does not support streaming (learned it the hard way). Regarding the chucks, the files that are being transferred are huge and must be chucked.

Thanks,

Moshe